# File not found with New GoogleMaps SDK for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, google-maps, xcode4.5

I been struggling with the new iOS google maps sdk for some time.
I worked according to the tutorial on: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

however whenever i tried to compile my simple project i get an error on line:

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

file not found...

BTW, I'm working with Xcode 4.5.1

Do you know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure that the framework (folder) was added to your project correctly?

Comment: Yes, i drag&drop the GoogleMaps.framework to my Framworks group (with copy files to destination group). I can see it also on Finder under my project

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry google map isn't supported yet for iPhone developers.

because an API key is not generated yet you need to wait for an email from Google. so don't bother applying this tutorial. because eventually it will not work.
click on the below link :

[Google Maps not working on iPhone simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007075/google-maps-not-working-on-iphone-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to drag both the .framework package and the .bundle package over into XCode.

.framework package is just the GoogleMaps.framework folder which is in the top-most level of the SDK zip.

.bundle package is found under GoogleMaps.framework/Resources, and is titled "GoogleMaps.bundle"

Answer (score 0):

Make sure .bundle file **is not copied** to the project folder when prompted.