# Google Maps SDK for iOS doesn't display map content

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the current version 1.1.2 of Google Maps SDK for iOS. The map only displays the Google logo, the current location and the added marker. But no map content whatsoever:

[image]

I correctly registered the API key:

```
BOOL result = [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"<my key>"];
```

the result is `YES` and I verified that the bundleIdentifier matches with the API console. I load the GMSMapView from a storyboard and set the camera in my `-viewDidLoad`:

```
self.mapView.camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:0 longitude:0 zoom:2];
```

This is logged by GMSMapView:

```
Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6
Failed to make complete framebuffer object 8cd6
Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.1.2.2533
GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 10)
GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 15)
```

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

I'm using Auto Layout. Apparently, in `-viewDidLoad` the Auto Layout hasn't yet done its work and my `GMSMapView` still had a CGRectZero frame. `GMSMapView` seems to react very picky on a zero frame.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

prior to setting the camera solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 16):

This could also be caused by not having the right bundle ID entered under the API key in your Google API Console.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case someone comes here and nothing works...

I was having this problem and got bored so I unzoomed the map and discovered I messed up with the location and my map center was in the middle of a desert!
Map was working just fine.

So try to unzoom, just in case.

Comment: Thank you, I had inverted the lat/long by  mistake and I was apparently in the arctic sea!

Comment: @ekscrypto You never know where development will take you. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have included both **GoogleMaps.framework** and **GoogleMapsM4B.framework** (Maps for Business) in your XCode project, remove **GoogleMapsM4B.framework**.

Otherwise you'll need to enable **Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work** through Enterprise Support portal instead of **Google Maps SDK for iOS** from Cloud Console.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem.The issue was I used two iOS Api keys in 2 different places in code.Please check whether you have used **correct API Key (iOS Key)** from google Api console.Use the same key through out your app.