# Google Maps does not load in iPad 3 device

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am doing a POC on Google Maps SDK integration for iPad. I am using the latest SDK from Google Map Developer portal (version:1.4.0.4450). I am setting the APIKey as suggested in the Maps developer page.

It works perfectly in the simulator. But while I am trying to run it to a device (iPad 3), it does not show  up the map content. Here are the logs from console:

```
2013-07-26 11:08:20.081 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 10)
2013-07-26 11:08:20.084 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 14)
2013-07-26 11:08:20.085 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] GMSZoomTableQuadTree lacks root zoom table for tile type (mapType: 15)
2013-07-26 11:08:35.038 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1e5b9dd0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f873c60 "The request timed out."}
2013-07-26 11:08:50.050 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1f8ad550 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1f8ad100 "The request timed out."}
2013-07-26 11:09:09.061 SampleGoogleMaps[69595:907] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 5). Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo=0x1e5b8f00 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out., NSUnderlyingError=0x1e588020 "The request timed out."}
```

Does anyone has come across this issue?. Can anyone suggest me solutions. I have given the solution that is given at: [Google Maps SDK for iOS doesn't display map content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799411/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-doesnt-display-map-content), but it did not work out!

Comment: any network connectivity issues in your ipad?

Comment: Sorry! Forgot to update the question and answer. It started working after sometime, I tried changing the API Keys by changing the bundle identifiers and then switched back to older bundle and key, then it started working.