# Google Maps not showing in device but working perfectly on simulator, iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I am following Google Maps Tutorial and maps are showing perfectly on simulator but when i try to run my google map application on device, Maps are not showing up. Can anybody help me with this issue?

I am pasting my viewDidLoad's code which i written in my ViewController for my Google Maps.

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(1.285, longitude: 103.848, zoom: 12)
                let mapView = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
                mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal
                mapView.indoorEnabled = false
                mapView.settings.compassButton = true
                mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
                self.view = mapView
```

Comment: How do you expect a frame with CGRectZero to be visible? Strange though that this works in the simulator. Can you try a frame that is bigger than 0?

Comment: I tried. Actually i am following offical google maps sdk tutorial and only just maps are not showing. The google logo is showing up on lower left corner of My device.

Comment: I think your google map key is not valid so you can check with other key

Comment: Can you post the **error description** while loading the code in device ? Also which version of Google Maps SDK  you are using for iOS ?

Comment: There is no error thrown by the code on my console window and i tried to create a bridging header and #import "GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h"  with it's location path in the target of the project. Still nothing happened on way of success!

Comment: may be something is blocked on internetconnection connected to your mobile which is not on your mac

Comment: yes! finally it's working. i just change my device ipod to 5s and my app is working like a charm. I guess it's a issue with that device.

Comment: Dear @Himanshu , check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15799411/google-maps-sdk-for-ios-doesnt-display-map-content) for further details. Just in case for future issues. Cheers ....  :)

Comment: Thanks! Verbose i will surely do the same.