# Google Maps API key may be invalid for your bundle ID

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

We have a Google API Key that have been working for the past few months but suddenly yesterday it stop working below is the error.

`2013-09-20 23:01:36.483 SampleApp[907:a0b] Google Maps SDK for iOS cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x18828d90 {data=<CFData 0x14d04c30 [0x6174ec8]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2013-09-20 23:01:36.484 SampleApp[907:a0b] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.company.SampleApp`

We were not able to find the account that own of the API key. Is there a way that we can Contact the Google Maps API team to request for help in identifying the account and help resolve the issue?

Comment: Did you change the app bundle id in Xcode? Clearly the api key is bundled with your app bundle id to prevent api abuse. If you changed the app bundle id, then you cannot use the same api key. Check that, or just apply for a new api key using the current app bundle id.

Comment: You can mail me with your API Key at brettmorgan@google.com. I'm guessing com.company.SampleApp isn't your actual app bundle id...

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I'm experiencing the same problem. I changed bundle name and then changed it back and even if I try to recreate app ID many times, I get the same message...

Answer (score 21):

I found that there is no difference for api key which surrounded with curly braces or not.

Please make sure "enable GoogleMap SDK for iOS"

You may also see [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007075/google-maps-not-working-on-iphone-simulator)

Comment: Also the api key IS NOT be surrounded with curly braces in my case [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"api_key"]; and works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: To elaborate on this, "Enable Google Maps SDK for iOS" has to be enabled in Google's developer console. I was encountering this error when I had enabled the SDK for Android and forgot to do it for iOS as well.

Comment: This was spot on.  I got caught up in checking code and making sure the API key matched and forgot to enable the service! (facepalm)

Answer (score 11):

step by step

```
1.- go Google ApisConsole

2.- select Services and activate Google Maps SDK for iOS
```

`3.- later select API Access and Create new iOS key with your bundle identifier example` com.example.myProject

```
4.- copy Api key in your Project  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"kajshdklasjhdakls_LTcJWZqpRJ1BQmHxX9i0lI"]; on AppDelegate
```

goodluck

Comment: Thanks a lot, 3 days trying to fix it. Lol.

Comment: Thank you. This finally fixed my issue and now I can see the map loading.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two possible fixes:

**Possible Fix 1**

In the line,

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"{AIzaSyDCPXPLUkK3UVrLr9msaS6-EsZ6UHbVgEq}"];
```

the api key should be surrounded with curly braces.

**Possible Fix 2**

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in your `AppDelegate`, the above line should come *before* you instantiate your root view controller, not after.

Comment: I was the same problem, but I solved removing the curly braces.

Answer (score 4):

Just my 2 cents; I enabled Google Maps for iOS in the services section of the API console after I had generated my API key which didn't work. I just deleted my key out and created a new one and hey presto (this was after a lot of testing, so it was definitely the issue, strangely).

Answer (score 1):

use this code: `NSLog(@"my bundle id is: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);`
for identify the bundle identifiers you need generated Api access in google apis.

for example: my Bundle identifier in my project x-code is `projects.example.mymap`, then you should copy and paste the same into apiaccess and generate this apikey.

if the problem persists, create other key and remove the last, use the new key in your app.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same exact problem, ended up here searching for the answer to no avail.  I was copying the API key on Google Apis and each time was seeing a "Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com." error.

So I decided to try typing out the API Key by hand and Voilà it worked.  Definitely worth a shot, maybe somehow there are special characters being passed via copy/paste.

Comment: Very weird, but this answer helped me. I basically copied the key from the Google APIs Console, then pasted it in my browser's URL bar, then copied it again and then pasting it in Xcode worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

just enable google map ios sdk from your account and do not use curlie braces you will easily able to load google map.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, its occur because of bundle name differences,

- iOS application name you used in the Google Map SDK and
- The organization name while creating Xcode project should be matched.
  Just match both names, your error will get resolved.

Answer (score 0):

pretty much all the answers on this page say the same thing.. which is the exact same thing as the instructions on the google maps sdk [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios)..

the one thing that no one mentions is that sometimes this key takes a while to propagate on the web (ie it may not be immediately recognized by your app).. so wait up a bit.

Also one thing I found a little different is that i did *not* add com to the beginning of my bundle identifier.. so you can try that as well.

Answer (score -1):

I was experiencing the same problem. In "Google Developers Console" you should do:

1. Push "Create new Key" button
2. Select "Server key"
3. Push "Create"
4. Use this key in your Xcode project