# not able to use Google map sdk in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am  working a simple iOS app into which I am integrating Google Maps. but not getting any result . 
i have used this steps

**step 1**:i have downloaded Google Maps Mobile SDK 
from this link [sdk ios](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/)

**step 2:** Create an API project in the Google APIs Console.

**step 3:** Select the Services pane in your API project, and enable the Google Maps SDK for iOS. This displays the Google Maps Terms of Service.

[image]
getting Active status Google APIs Console.
[image]
step 4:i Selected the API Access pane in the console, and click Create new iOS key.

[image]

and then i added API Key in AppDelegate.m like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>
@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        NSLog(@"Current identifier: %@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]);
        [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIzaSTyurcyzpvoRv3gCPJRiw7Dc6dXkTMfOI2w"];
        return YES;
    }
```

**but i am not getting result. in log i got this error**

```
Gmap[3836:883464] Current identifier: com.example.Gmap
2015-02-06 14:39:41.790 Gmap[3836:883464] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) version: 1.9.13516.0
2015-02-06 14:39:42.014 Gmap[3836:883464] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f922a67fcd0 {data=<CFData 0x7f922d4615a0 [0x1049039a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-02-06 14:39:42.213 Gmap[3836:883464] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f922a4d7540 {data=<CFData 0x7f922d48dd90 [0x1049039a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-02-06 14:39:46.594 Gmap[3836:883464] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f922a6a4a50 {data=<CFData 0x7f922a798c00 [0x1049039a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-02-06 14:39:55.528 Gmap[3836:883464] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f922d49fed0 {data=<CFData 0x7f922a6406e0 [0x1049039a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-02-06 14:39:55.529 Gmap[3836:883464] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f922d49fed0 {data=<CFData 0x7f922a6406e0 [0x1049039a0]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-02-06 14:39:55.529 Gmap[3836:883464] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.example.Gmap
```

Can someone help to find the mistake here. what is missing here. not able to get why this error is coming .this simulator screen after running apps. [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007075/google-maps-not-working-on-iphone-simulator

Comment: i have used this . not getting . please check my steps.@sandhaya

Comment: reset once ur simulator and check once ur bundle id is same with which u gave in api creation time must be equal, and otherwise plz generate new api key

Comment: follow this step by step ..http://vikrambahl.com/google-maps-ios-xcode-storyboards/ ..it works for me

Comment: have you check my question .when i am seting the bundle id . i have taken screen shot .and i printed it in nslog both are same .

Comment: ya r u using same bundle id  in project?

Comment: i used same step @Jigs

Comment: yes @sandhaya com.example.Gmap.see

Comment: Why are trying to use `Google Maps SDK for Work iOS` (business) or `Google Maps SDK for iOS`? You are using `#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>` but you are trying to generate a Key for another SDK (simple IOS)

Comment: download this framework https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start?hl=BG ... and "Finally, add your API key to your AppDelegate `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>"`

Comment: when i am going in this link.its redirect mr same link what is used Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work

Comment: try this link.. or try to go (manual).. to   `Google Maps SDK for iOS' not for Work https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/?hl=BG

Comment: Your API key may be invalid for your bundle ID

Answer (score 3):

As we have already said in the comments, you are using the wrong library - `Google Maps SDK for Work iOS` (business) but you are trying to generate a Key for `Google Maps SDK for iOS` (you are using: `#import <GoogleMapsM4B/GoogleMaps.h>` instead `#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>`

Comment: i want to use Google Maps SDK for Work iOS (business)

Comment: Then ... you must enable `Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work` not `Google Maps SDK for iOS`

Answer (score 0):

For the GoogleMaps framework you need to install cocoa pods and in then type the following in terminal `pod try GoogleMaps`
This will install the pod and and download the googlemaps framework. It will 
open a sample project on completion. You can find the framework and map bundle in the project. Using this framework my issue was resolved. Below is the complete path of the framework on my machine:
/private/var/folders/9b/w5tw8dwx3vsddqw1g0r1rksr0000gn/T/CocoaPods/Try

Hope this helps :)