# iOS ,Google Map Error: Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). 
Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
(com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x7f95f4811190 
{data=<CFData 0x7f95f24df240 [0x1030a2eb0]>
{length = 145, capacity = 256,bytes =     
0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
```

I need help with this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide an `API KEY` for your application. You can follow the steps in [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#step_5_get_an_ios_api_key) to create an `API_KEY` from [Google Developer Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project). 
*(note: the sample `API_KEY` in the documentation page will probably throw the error, so dont use it, create your own one)*

After you get the `API KEY` from your developer console, you can paste it in the `AppDelegate` file.

If you are developing an Objective-C app, do this:

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];
```

If you are developing a Swift app, do this:

```
GMSServices.provideAPIKey("YOUR_API_KEY");
```

(replace `YOUR_API_KEY` with your actual key).

Comment: @Ghost Clock, have my answer solved your problem? If so, would you mind to mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: You need to download the GoogleMaps framework via cocoa pods. Please find the instructions for the same on this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362587/not-able-to-use-google-map-sdk-in-ios/31852044#31852044

Comment: Cocoapods can help you easily integrate Google Maps into your application, but your comment is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I was facing the same issue but after changing the framework it worked and yes you can work with coocoapods directly but for those who don't use cocoa pods this was the work around