# Google Maps sdk ios Api error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps-sdk-ios

I try to show the map on the simulator and I tried so much to sold this problem but I always have this error how can I fixed please ?

```
**2016-05-24 14:32:41.295 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 7 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:32:41.879 Menti[40241:2494765] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) version: 1.13.24482.0
    2016-05-24 14:32:42.389 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 6 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:32:44.661 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 5 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:32:49.102 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 4 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:32:57.173 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:33:13.234 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:33:45.302 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 1 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:34:49.602 Menti[40241:2494765] ClientParametersRequest failed, 0 attempts remaining (0 vs 7). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:34:49.602 Menti[40241:2494765] Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) cannot connect or validate APIKey: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c48544d 4c3e0a3c 48454144 3e0a3c54 49544c45 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f5449 544c453e 0a3c2f48 4541443e 0a3c424f 44592042 47434f4c 4f523d22 23464646 46464622 20544558 543d2223 30303030 3030223e 0a3c4831 3e426164 20526571 75657374 3c2f4831 3e0a3c48 323e4572 726f7220 3430303c 2f48323e 0a3c2f42 4f44593e 0a3c2f48 544d4c3e 0a>}
    2016-05-24 14:34:49.602 Menti[40241:2494765] Your key may be invalid for your bundle ID: com.menti.maps**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a key for your application in google portal right. So in that, you have specified projects bundle identifier. You have to use the same bundle identifier for your application also. And also in App delegate method you have to use the same key.

Please follow the link

1.[Google Map Integration for IOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start#step_4_get_an_api_key)

2. https://www.codeschool.com/courses/exploring-google-maps-for-ios

**Please note below point also**
**If you want to practice on google maps from iOS devices then just download the GoogleMaps.framework from the below link**: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios

**If you want to use GoogleMapsM4B.framework in your project then**

1. You should request support on the Enterprise Support portal(Google's website)
2. You must enable Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work not Google Maps SDK for iOS in Google’s console website.

You can find the key differences between the Google Maps SDK for iOS and the Google Maps Mobile SDK for Work(M4B) in the below link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/ios/

Hope this will Help You.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are using wrong sdk.

as error suggests `Google Maps SDK for iOS (M4B) cannot connect or validate APIKey`  means you are using Google Maps SDK Business version sdk and may be you are using right API key.

import correct `Google Maps SDK` and use appropriate API key.

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
```

Also check here: [not able to use Google map sdk in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28362587/not-able-to-use-google-map-sdk-in-ios)

Answer (score 1):

Just enable "Google Maps SDK for Ios and Android on Google Cloud Platform Console