# Getting error com.google.HTTPStatus code 400 while resolving the address using GMSReverseGeocodeResponse

Tags: iphone, google-maps, ios8

I am trying to resolve the address (trying to convert latitude & longitude to readable address) using [[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:{}];. I am not getting any response data and following error

***ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)" UserInfo=0x17e080b0 {data={length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}***

Comment: Are you using a valid Google Maps iOS API key?

Comment: Also, make sure you enable the GoogleMap SDK for iOS in the Google APIs Console as seen in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15028369/4241842) answer.

Comment: i have a valid API key. And also enabled the GoogleMap SDK for iOS.

Comment: @not_a_bot is there any thing else I have to look into, where I may be wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code. Is there an example that you're following? Which other APIs have you enabled in the APIs console? Are you seeing this on a simulator or an actual device? Also, which version of the iOS SDK are you using?

Comment: I am using iOS 8.3 as my base SDK. in ***AppDelegate.m*** I have used this line of code ***[GMSServices provideAPIKey:GOOGLE_API_KEY];*** I am referring following link https://developers.google.com/places/ios/

Comment: Following is the code for getting address from coordinate. ***[[GMSGeocoder geocoder] reverseGeocodeCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(40.4375, -3.6818) completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse* response, NSError* error) {
    NSLog(@"reverse geocoding results:");***

Comment: I have same issue here :( I will try to figure it out

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue. My problem was the Google Maps SDK for iOS wich was not enabled :/

So be carefull of the API key (and the associated bundle ID) and check if the right API is activated.