# GMS reverseGeocodeCoordinate returns statusCode 400 error

Tags: swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

This has been function in my application for quite a while and only stopped working recently.

```
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, onSuccess : @escaping LocationUpdateSuccess) {
    let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in
        if let address = response?.firstResult() {
            if let lines = address.lines! as? [String] {
                let title = lines.joined(separator: " ")
                if (title.characters.count) > 3 {
                        print(title)
                        onSuccess(coordinate, title)

                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print("Error In Reverse GeoCoding \n \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, Here's what I'm sending as the parameter values

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D
- latitude : 31.51774603759463
- longitude : 74.340778893683378
```

Here's the exact text of the error when I make the request

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 400.)
```

Similarly

```
GMSPlacesClient().autocompleteQuery
```

wouldn't respond with results as it used to in the following function

```
func autoCompleteQuery(searchText: String) {

    if searchText.characters.count != 0 {
        self.tableView.alpha = 1

        let countryFilter = GMSAutocompleteFilter()
        countryFilter.country = "US"


        var areaBounds : GMSCoordinateBounds? = nil
        if let lastSavedLocation = MyLocationManager.sharedInstance.lastSavedLocation
        {
            let lat = lastSavedLocation.coordinate.latitude
            let long = lastSavedLocation.coordinate.longitude

            let offset = 200.0 / 1000.0;
            let latMax = lat + offset;
            let latMin = lat - offset;
            let lngOffset = offset * cos(lat * M_PI / 200.0);
            let lngMax = long + lngOffset;
            let lngMin = long - lngOffset;
            let initialLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latMax, longitude: lngMax)
            let otherLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latMin, longitude: lngMin)
            areaBounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: initialLocation, coordinate: otherLocation)
        }

        placesClient.autocompleteQuery(searchText, bounds: areaBounds, filter: countryFilter, callback: { (result, error) -> Void in

            self.nearbyPlacesList.removeAll()
            if result == nil {
                print("Error in autocompleteQuery -> \(error?.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            for result in result!{
                if let result = result as? GMSAutocompletePrediction {
                    self.nearbyPlacesList.append((id: result.placeID!, name: result.attributedFullText.string))
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        })
    } else {
        self.tableView.alpha = 0
    }
}
```

with the following error message.

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. An internal error occurred in the Places API library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/support).
```

I've looked into answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138764/getting-error-com-google-httpstatus-code-400-while-resolving-the-address-using-g), reinstalling the pods and what not.

I also matched the bundle identifier, lifted restrictions on API quotas, disabled and enabled the SDKs again from Google's Cloud console as shown below

[image: Google's Console Settings Screenshot]

but nothing worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this post sometime later, initialising the GMS Services and Places with right keys was the problem.

```
 GMSServices.provideAPIKey(<API_KEY_GOES_HERE>)
 GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey(<API_KEY_GOES_HERE>)
```

I was using an old key from a project which was no longer active on Google Cloud Console, hence returning a 400 Error. Hope this helps someone ;)